# Unidirectional one-to-many mapping in Hibernate generates redundant updates

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have defined two classes, Parent and Child. The parent can have a list of children.

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(...)
    @SequenceGenerator(...)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private List<Child> children;

    public Parent() {
        children = new ArrayList<Child>();
    }

    public void addChild(Child child) { children.add(child); }
}

@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(...)
    @SequenceGenerator(...)
    private long id;

    // The "Child" table in the db also has a not-null "parent_id" column.
}
```

If I add a bunch of children to the list and persist the parent everything works as expected: Hibernate gets the sequence values, stores the parent and then stores all the children.

However, after doing all this, it updates all the children, setting the "parent_id" to the value it was already set to in the insert!

The generated SQL looks like this:

```
insert into PARENT (id) values (1)
insert into CHILD (parent_id, id) values (1, 1)
insert into CHILD (parent_id, id) values (1, 2)
insert into CHILD (parent_id, id) values (1, 3)
update CHILD set parent_id = 1 WHERE id = 1
update CHILD set parent_id = 1 WHERE id = 2
update CHILD set parent_id = 1 WHERE id = 3
```

If I make this association bidirectional it works fine, but then I need a reference to the parent in my child class and that's something I want to avoid.

The repository is a Spring Data JPA repository:

```
public interface ParentRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Parent, Long> {}
```

The (simplified) code that creates and saves the objects:

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
parent.addChild(new Child());
parent.addChild(new Child());
repo.save(parent);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: @chsdk, what additional code do you need? If it helps, I'm using a Spring Data JPA repository on which I call save(parent). Both parent and children are completely immutable after creation by using a builder.

Comment: Try to add `mappedBy`attribute to your mapping like this: `@OneToMany(mappedBy ="parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` where parent should be the name of the Parent field in the Child class.

Comment: @chsdk as I mentioned in the question, I don't have a reference to the parent in my child. It is a unidirectional association.

Comment: Ah Ok I missed that.

Comment: That's fine :) I had already tried that suggestion though, and it does indeed work as expected. But I don't want to reference the parent from my child object.

Comment: Can you show us the code that populates these objects and calls 'save'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
```

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed work! The semantics are a bit confusing, but my understanding is that you add these settings because the Child is already inserting/updating itself (due to cascade) and the Parent does not also need to do this?

Comment: this way will not insert the FK to the table. If you wish the values of FK you should put yes in insertable/updatable. :)